# How to add research highlights before abstract and graphical abstract after abstract?

Tags: graphics, abstract

for a journal in elsevier named 'Applied Surface Science', it is mandatory to put research highlights and graphical abstract. The research highlights is to be placed before the abstract and the graphical abstract is to be placed after the abstract. I am using elsevier template but can not add these 2 things. I am attaching the code here that I am using. The error it shows is:
Latex Error: Environment Highlights Undefined and Latex Error: Environment graphicalabstract Undefined

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,numbers,sort&compress]{elsarticle}
```

Necessary packages for my document inserted.

```
\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
```

title and author description provided

```
    \begin{highlights}
    \item Research highlights item 1
    \item Research highlights item 2
    \item Research highlights item 3
    \end{highlights}
\begin{abstract}
```

abstract provided

```
\end{abstract}
\begin{graphicalabstract}

\end{graphicalabstract}
```

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: Hello and welcome, you can put a complete MWE, not just parts of it, so it's easier to understand your problem.

Comment: Which version of the `elsarticle.cls` do you use?

Comment: Hi Leandriis, I used version 1.20b

Comment: Probably version 1.20b (wich must be quite old) does not yet support the use of highlights and graphica abstracts. The most recent version 3.2 does.